# how to run python inside netbeans?

Tags: python, netbeans

I installed the plugin for python and it detects the python code, but how do I run it from Netbeans?

Comment: FIXED!!I started a new Python project and ran the main file, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install python first.

Then Netbeans will detect the installation and you can run it from there. More info here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python